# Relative Clause | who, whom, whose

Tags: relative-clauses

Is it true that "who", "whom, and "whose" can only be used for humans? If it's true, then are these sentences correct?

"*He bought a car **which** runs fast*"

"*He was wearing a cap **which** was black*"

Comment: _Whom_ is effectively dead in Modern English, and should not be used by English learners. You can strand prepositions instead of moving them. _Who did she say she heard from?_ is fine and doesn't need _whom_, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

> "He bought a car which runs fast" & "He was wearing a cap which was black"?

These are both correct, but probably should be punctuated with a comma before "which", or the relative pronoun "that" could have been used.

You should not use "a car who runs fast", except as poetic personification - rhetorically pretending that a car is a person.

You might see "a dog who runs fast", since we often treat pets as people.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that "who", "whom, and "whose" can only be used for humans?

[You can use **whose** as a relative pronoun for inanimate objects](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/whose-used-for-inanimate-objects), as in "The tree, whose leaves were brown..."

Yes, we would say "The tree **which** had brown leaves", but English doesn't have a relative pronoun like "which's", so we use *whose* for both people and inanimate objects.

*Who* and *whom* are only used for people, or sometimes animals and inanimate objects that we are treating like people.

> If it's true, then are these sentences correct?

Yes, they are both correct.  I'm not sure how that is related to your first question, since they could be correct whether the answer to the first question was "yes" or "no".

Answer (score 0):

The sentences are correct.

He bought a car **which** runs fast.

He was wearing a cap **which** was black.

**Who** refers to people and **which** refers to things. We can use **that** instead of 'who' or 'which'.

He bought a car **that** runs fast.

He was wearing a cap **that** was black.

[ The man **who** came here yesterday is my friend. or The man **that** came here yesterday is my friend.

I know the man **who** came here yesterday. or I know the man **that** came here yesterday. ]